# Find the value of :

Tags: calculus, summation

Find the value of $$\frac{\sqrt{100+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{9999}}}{\sqrt{100-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{100-\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{100-\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\sqrt{100-\sqrt{9999}}}.$$

Comment: FWIW: If you replace $100$ with $m$ and $9999$ with $m^2-1$ you always seem to get $1+\sqrt{2}$ for any $m\in\mathbb N$ (says mathematica).

Comment: Even the following seems to hold: $\frac{\sum_{i=k}^{m^2-k}\sqrt{m+\sqrt{i}}}{\sum_{i=k}^{m^2-k}\sqrt{m-\sqrt{i}}}=1+\sqrt{2}$ for all $k>0$ and $2k\leq m^2$. I couldn't make much of it, though.

Comment: Wait, give me a second to get my calculator out. This is going to take a while.

Answer (score 2):

It is curious that this is listed as "precalculus", because I'm not sure that a solid answer can be given for an exact value of this ratio. If you're allowed some calculus, then it's easy to see that the ratio can be written as

$$
 S = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{9999}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{n/10000}}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{9999}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{n/10000}}}}
$$
From this, we can see that it's a quite high-resolution approximation to the ratio of integrals

$$
 S \approx \frac{\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}dx}{\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}dx} = \frac{\frac{8}{15}(\sqrt{2}+1)}{\frac{8}{15}} = \sqrt{2}+1
$$
And this is a good approximation to the ratio. I cannot see a way to get a simple algebraic value for it without calculus.

Comment: I think it should be rather $\sqrt{2}+1$.

Comment: Ah, right. Typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: changed the tags.

Comment: BTW: how did you compute the integrals? They don't look so simple to me.

Comment: It's quite simple, really. Let $\sqrt{1 \pm \sqrt{x}} = u$, so $x=(u^2-1)^2$ and $dx = 4(u^2-1)udu$. Both integrals become $4\int (u^2-1)u^2du$, which is trivial to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can proof for a fraction of the form
$\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$
that $a_i=r b_i$ for all $i$ then obviously 
$$\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}=r$$
Hence, in the fraction given in the problem statement it suffices to show that
$$\frac{\sqrt{100+\sqrt{5000-i}}+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{5000+i}}}{\sqrt{100-\sqrt{5000-i}}+\sqrt{100-\sqrt{5000+i}}}=\sqrt{2}+1.$$
(Just sum the terms in the numerator and the denominator from $i=1$ to $4999$ and divide by $2$). To show the last equation set $100=\sqrt{2x}$, hence $5000=x$. Then it needs to be shown that
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x-i}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x+i}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x-i}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+i}}}=\sqrt{2}+1.$$
For the proof see the [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338109/proof-for-an-equality-involving-square-roots) (thanks Boris Novikov). Thus the value of the expression is $\sqrt{2}+1$.