# Proof for an equality involving square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

While trying to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337880/find-the-value-of#comment728381_337880), I stumbled upon the following equality
$$
\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x+k}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x-k}}=(\sqrt2+1)
\left(
\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+k}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x-k}}
\right)
$$
It seems to hold for any $x$ and $k$ in $\mathbb R$ such that all the square roots are well defined. If it can be proven, the proof of the above mentioned problem is immediate. However, I couldn't find a proof yet. I always have some surds left over.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Sorry I misread. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $a=\sqrt{2}+1$ and write the equation as follows:
$$
\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x+k}}-a\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+k}}=a\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x-k}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x-k}}
$$
Squaring both sides, we get
$$
(1+2a-a^2)\sqrt{x+k}=(1+2a-a^2)\sqrt{x-k}
$$

$\ldots$

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks a lot. Didn't see wood for all the roots$\ldots$